# Add quotes and new delimiter around space delimited words

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have the following string

```
y10_zcis y10_nom y10_infl y20_zcis y20_infl y30_zcis
```

I would like to transform this to

```
"y10_zcis", "y10_nom", "y10_infl", "y20_zcis", "y20_infl", "y30_zcis"
```

I accomplished something similar with the extremely ugly:

```
$ cat in.txt | sed 's/ /\'$'\n/g' | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1",/g' | tr -d '\n'


"y10_zcis","y10_nom","y10_infl","y20_zcis","y20_infl","y30_zcis",
```

But that feels like an utter failure, and it doesn't take care of the last unwanted `,` (but perhaps this is best to just delete afterwards)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
sed -e 's| |", "|g' -e 's|^|"|g' -e 's|$|"|g' in.txt
```

Where

- `'s| |", "|g'` will replace every space with `", "`
- `'s|^|"|g'` while at the beginning there's no space, you must specify with `^` the beginning of the line, so you're telling, put `"` at the beginning.
- `'s|$|"|g'` same thing but specifying the end of every line with `$`

**UPDATE**

As @don_crissti pointed out, you can do it shorter with the following

```
sed 's| |", "|g;s|.*|"&"|'
```

Where

- `;` separate each instruction
- `.*` matches the entire line.
- `&` an ampersand on the RHS is replaced by the entire expression matched on the LHS, in this case `.*`

  *RHS=Right hand side*

  *LHS=Left hand side*

Comment: Very nice, would you mind explaining how it works? Thanks

Comment: @luffe updated!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps `awk`

```
awk -vOFS=', ' '{for (k=1; k<=NF; ++k) $k="\""$k"\""; print}' file
"y10_zcis", "y10_nom", "y10_infl", "y20_zcis", "y20_infl", "y30_zcis", "y30_nom", "y30_infl"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\+\)/"\1",/g; s/,$//' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% sed 's/\([^ ]\+\)/"\1",/g; s/,$//' <<<'y10_zcis y10_nom y10_infl y20_zcis y20_infl y30_zcis'   
"y10_zcis", "y10_nom", "y10_infl", "y20_zcis", "y20_infl", "y30_zcis"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
perl -lane '$,=", "; foreach(@F) {s/^|$/"/g; push(@f, $_)}; print(@f)' <<<'y10_zcis y10_nom y10_infl y20_zcis y20_infl y30_zcis'
```

- `$, = ", "`: sets the output field separator to `,`;
- `foreach(@F) {s/^|$/"/g; push(@f, $_)}`: for each space-separated field, wraps the field into double quotes and appends it `@f`;
- `print(@f)`: prints the elements of `@f` separated by the output field separator.

```
% perl -lane '$,=", "; foreach(@F) {s/^|$/"/g; push(@f, $_)}; print(@f)' <<<'y10_zcis y10_nom y10_infl y20_zcis y20_infl y30_zcis'
"y10_zcis", "y10_nom", "y10_infl", "y20_zcis", "y20_infl", "y30_zcis"
%
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using bash and your string is already in a variable:

```bash
$ a="y10_zcis y10_nom y10_infl y20_zcis y20_infl y30_zcis"
$
```

Then you can do this:

```bash
$ echo \"${a// /\", \"}\"
"y10_zcis", "y10_nom", "y10_infl", "y20_zcis", "y20_infl", "y30_zcis"
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet Another Way, using the shell (`for`, `printf`), and a final `sed` hack:

```
( for word in $(cat in.txt)
    do printf '"%s", ' $word; done; 
  printf '"\n' ) | 
  sed 's/, "$//'
```

Comment: Avoid the `for stuff in $(cat file)` construct... besides, you're already using `sed` so use only `sed` for this job. If you wanted to do it shell only, you could run (with bash4): `mapfile -t stuff <infile; printf '"%s"\n' "${stuff[@]// /\", \"}"`